# Is It possible to Get list of IP address connected in LAN,in C# without using win32 API library.?

Tags: c#, winapi, networking, windows-7

I'm trying to get list of IP address which are connected in LAN,
Is it possible to get without using win32 API library.(Netapi32.dll).
Any Idea to get an Without using Unmanaged win32 dynamic library.target to Windows 7 operating system

Comment: It looks like you're using @Darryl Braaten's answer.  If so, you should mark that answer as the accepted answer.  If you want to discuss how to speed up the code you posted, you should post that as a new question.  The model of StackOverflow is one question, one answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) to ping every IP in your subnet if you get a response there is a machine using that ip.  If you don't get a response that ip is available, or the machine is ignoring pings.

**Updated to add code to do this in parallel.**

```
public string IPList()
        {
            string myipsplit = string.Empty;
            string localhostname = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] paddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(localhostname);
            string myip = paddresses.Where( ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            string[] myiparray = myip.Split(new[] { '.' });
            for (int j = 1; j < myiparray.Length; j++)
                myipsplit += myiparray[j - 1] + ".";
            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            var results = new string[0x100];
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(1, 0x100, id =>
                           {
                              var pingSender = new Ping();
                              string ls = myipsplit + id;
                              PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(ls, 100);
                              if (reply != null)
                                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                                        results[id] = reply.Address.ToString();
                            });

            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            results.All(x => { sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", x);
                                 return true;
            });
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Updated to be .Net 2.0

```
private delegate void MyPing(int id);
        public string IPList2()
        {

            string myipsplit = string.Empty;
            string localhostname = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] paddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(localhostname);
            string myip = paddresses.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            string[] myiparray = myip.Split(new[] { '.' });
            for (int j = 1; j < myiparray.Length; j++)
                myipsplit += myiparray[j - 1] + ".";
            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            var results = new string[0x100];
            MyPing ping = 
             id =>
            {
                string ls = myipsplit + id;
                var pingSender = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(ls, 100);
                if (reply != null)
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        results[id] = reply.Address.ToString();
            };
            var asyncResults = new IAsyncResult[0x100];
            for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
            {
                asyncResults[i] = ping.BeginInvoke(i, null, null);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
            {
                ping.EndInvoke(asyncResults[i]);
            }
            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
            {
                if (results[i]!=null)
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", results[i]);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: obviously your are correct,but method is targeted for C#.Net 2.0.

Comment: Updated to do the parallel stuff manually.  If you can't use lamba's you can update to use an old style delegate.

Comment: @arun I wrote that on Windows 7.  What does not work for you?  Are you getting any errors?  Are you running as a limited user or an admin?

Comment: Darryl,the prob is due to virtual networkinteface and  IPAddress[] paddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(localhostname);
            string myip = paddresses.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault().ToString(); following code fails to get exact physical Network interface adapter.  Any have thanks i spared the code with some limitation

Answer (score 1):

```
public string IPList()
        {
            var pingSender = new Ping();
            string port = string.Empty;
            string myipsplit = string.Empty;
            string localhostname = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] paddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(localhostname);
            string myip = paddresses[0].ToString();
            string[] myiparray = myip.Split(new[] {'.'});
            for (int j = 1; j < myiparray.Length; j++)
                myipsplit += myiparray[j - 1] + ".";
            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            for (int i = 0; i < 0x100; i++)
            {
                string ls = myipsplit + i;
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(ls, 0);
                if (reply != null)
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        port += reply.Address + "+";
            }
            Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            return port;
        }
```

Comment: use System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For to do a bunch of pings in parallel.

Comment: I added some working parallel code to my answer, it also fixes some bugs in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NetworkInterface` object to get all the machines network interfaces.

```
var networkCards = System.Net.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach(var card in networkCards)
    Console.WriteLine(card.GetPhysicalAddress());
```

Comment: I'm not asking my physical address.

Comment: Be clear I want to collect all IP address which are connected in LAN,not Physcial address .like 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.15