# Send Multiple Pings without waiting for reply Windows C#

Tags: c#, windows, wifi, ping, triangulation

Im currently doing research towards my final year BSc project. The final product will include indoor location tracking functionality. The traditional, or most utilised method seems to be RSSI triangulation, but I am keen to attempt to improve the accuracy of the PING method as I think this would be better suited to locations that may suffer from signal attenuation (the locations I am intending to use the device may have a moderate ammount of radio interference).

I was wondering if it was possible to write software in c# that would mimick the ping flood ability of linux ping utility(which enable the sending of multiple pings without waiting for a reply). I hypothesize that using multiple pings and timing them from the first to the last will enable the usage of the method over shorter distances.

Many Thanks

Dylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this hope it works fine

```
private ArrayList IPList()
        {
            string myipsplit = string.Empty;
            string myip =
                Dns.GetHostAddresses(
                    Dns.GetHostName())[0].ToString();
            string[] myiparray = myip.Split(new[] {'.'});
            for (int j = 1; j < myiparray.Length; j++)
                myipsplit += myiparray[j - 1] + ".";
            var sb = new ArrayList();
            MyPing ping = delegate(int id)
                              {
                                  string ls = myipsplit + id;
                                  var pingSender = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
                                  PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(ls, 0);
                                  if (reply != null)
                                      if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                                          sb.Add(ls);
                              };
            var asyncResults = new IAsyncResult[0x100];
            for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
                asyncResults[i] = ping.BeginInvoke(i, null, null);
            for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
                ping.EndInvoke(asyncResults[i]);
            return sb;
        }

        #region Nested type: MyPing

        private delegate void MyPing(int id);

        #endregion
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill try it when im in the development stage. Right now im still researching the possibilities :)

Comment: .Net 4.0  parallel.For loop executes comparatively faster than you expect. all d best for your research...

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978896/is-it-possible-to-get-list-of-ip-address-connected-in-lan-in-c-without-using-win

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Ping.SendAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e6kc029.aspx) function. As stated in the MSDN page:

> Each call to this method executes in a separate thread that is
>   automatically allocated from the thread pool. When the asynchronous
>   operation completes, it raises the PingCompleted event. To specify the
>   method that is called when SendAsync raises the event, you must add a
>   PingCompletedEventHandler delegate to the event before calling
>   SendAsync.

Here's a splendid example on how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63bsyf0.aspx

Comment: You can have a look at this thread for an example on how to use the SendAsync() function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602845/ping-sendasync-returned-replay-from-0-0-0-0-how-to-get-pinged-address