# Dns.GetHostEntry or Dns.Resolve. How to?

Tags: c#, sockets

```
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("192.168.182.1");
        IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 14372);


        wSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        wSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
```

This is how I create socket connection. As you see host IP is set manually. But how to get it automaticaly? I dont want to recompile my application for different networks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978896/is-it-possible-to-get-list-of-ip-address-connected-in-lan-in-c-sharp-without-usi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Socket.Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) on MSDN:

> If you do not care which local address is assigned, you can create an
>   `IPEndPoint` using `IPAddress.Any` as the address parameter, and the
>   underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate network
>   address. This might help simplify your application if you have
>   multiple network interfaces.

From [IPAddress.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx):

> The `Socket.Bind` method uses the `Any` field to indicate that a `Socket`
>   instance must listen for client activity on all network interfaces.
>   The `Any` field is equivalent to `0.0.0.0` in dotted-quad notation.

Thus, you could simply replace your first three lines with:

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 14372);
```